# Event after Create User - ASP.NET Membership 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am going to use Create User Wizard in order to let a user create their account for this company web site. I'd like to add one more step after new account is created, but I can't find the way to do it. What I want to do is that verify the use as a current employee of this company. This is not open web site for everyone, so only current employee can create a user account in this site. 
This is the step that I need to implement.

1. Ask employee ID and Name to verify whether he or she is current employee or not.
2. If yes, the Create User Wizard step will start. I will show the Employee ID on top of this wizard.
3. When a user account is created successfully, I need to insert UserID from aspnet_Users table and Employee ID into additional table as a reference.

I can't figure where I can do step 3 for coding.

I am guessing that I need to do it on "Create User" button event, But I also need to know whether a user account is successfully created or not.

Please, let me know.

Comment: are you using ASP.NET Membership service?

Comment: Yes, I am. I added it to Title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I last did this, I just subscribed to CreatedUser and it worked great for me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.createduser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own form, asking for the required information. In your case the ID and Name.

Once you verify that the ID and Name are the right ones, you can use one of the `Membership.CreateUser` [(docs here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership) overloads to create the user.

If you need any extra functionality, lte me know